# Windows Hotkey to switch between Display Configurations for 3+ Monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have 3 Monitors (2 Monitors + 1 TV) and I have 2 setups, in which way I want to use them. I either want to use the 2 monitors on an extended desktop, or I want to use the TV only (working vs. gaming).

Is there any (preferably built-in) Windows 10-tool, to save and switch between such setups? Maybe even with shortcut?
I know <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for cycling between basic setups, but the given ones are obviously for two screens only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the free
[Monitor Profile Switcher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/monitorswitcher/).

It sets up an icon in the traybar that can save the current configuration under
a given name, assign hotkeys and switch configurations:

[image]